# Python: Using openssl via subprocess to decrypt with a variable password

Tags: python, encryption, openssl

I am trying to use subprocess to run an openssl command via a python script to decrypt an already encrypted file with the known password.

The code I have works, but I want to be able to save a password as a variable, i.e. `pass = 'password'` and input that variable into the subprocess call rather than have it statically as `pass:password` . Without worrying about how I get the password saved to the variable, and just focusing on passing it as a variable to the subprocess call, is this possible?

I was reading the PASS PHRASE ARGUEMENTS section of the OpenSSL man page, so I'm curious if I should be using one of the other options (`env:var, file:pathname, fd:number, or stdin`). However it's hard to find examples of them in use, so I'm not sure.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def decryptfile():
decryptFile = subprocess.Popen(["openssl", "aes-256-cbc", "-d", "-a", "-in", "pw.txt", 
                                "-out", "pw.dec.txt", "-pass", "pass:password"]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with python for quite some time now, and I know how to store output from the subprocess module into a user defined variable as follows

```
import subprocess

value = subprocess.getoutput("Your Command")
print("The variable value is holding: {}".format(value))
```

As far as getting the password as a variable try splitting the data from the subprocess output (now stored in variable) into a list. You can also format that list to what you need. You can set a password variable with a value equivalent to a value inside of that list by indexing that lists values, example:

```
hello = subprocess.getoutput("echo hello")
list_hello = list(hello)
# print the index value of 1 to return hello
# use string interpolation
print("Second value in subprocess call is : {}".format(list_hello[1]))
# store the value of "hello" in "echo hello"
# to a variable
hello_str = str(list_hello[1])
# you should cast the variable to a string
# data type just to be safe
print("The value of hello_str is: {}".format(hello_str))
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted, I'll try to clarify it better. I need to be able to input an already defined variable into the subprocess call itself, i.e. instead of using 'pass:password' it uses my variable and doesn't wait for me to type the password into the terminal. The stuff about storing the output is definitely going to be useful later in my program though

Answer (score 0):

Use string interpolation

```
value = "my_value"
subprocess.call("commands {}".format(value), shell=True)
```

Use that string interpolation method to call/include your variable with your ssl command (password)

Comment: Hope that helps, or at least points you in the right direction

Comment: Thanks I'll try to work that in right now and let you know how it goes!